# What is the equivalent of is.na() function in r to python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, na

I am having trouble figuring out what the equivalent of is.na() function in r to python is. I am using np.nan but it does not work. What I am trying to do is add all the elements in a list before I reach an NA element. Here is my problem:

```
import numpy as np

x=[3,6,7,np.nan,-3,0]

k=len(x)

total_before_NA=0

for i in range(0,k):

    if (np.nan(x[i])):
        break
    total_before_NA= total_before_NA + x[i]

print(total_before_NA)
```

The answer I should be getting is 16 without using the sum function. Am I using the correct function? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.isnan()` to locate `NaN`, and then `np.argwhere()` to find the indices. Find the first index with `min()` and finally use `np.sum` on the slice before the first index with `NaN`:

```
index_first_nan = np.argwhere(np.isnan(x)).min()
np.sum(x[0:index_first_nan])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can use `np.isnan` to check for NaN values.

```py
import numpy as np

x=[3,6,7,np.nan,-3,0]

k=len(x)
total_before_NA=0

for i in range(0,k):

    if (np.isnan(x[i])):
        break
    total_before_NA= total_before_NA + x[i]

print(total_before_NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any R, but it seems that what you want to do is sum up all the values in your list that come before the NA. If so, then I'd suggest to use `index()` to obtain the index of that first NA and then simple slicing and summing:

```
i = x.index(np.nan)
total_before_NA = sum(x[:i])
```

That will make `total_before_NA` 16 in your example.